# How do you solve this using recurrence iteration method?

Tags: data-structures

T(n) = 3T(n-2) + c
This is what i have solved to far [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xczaz.jpg)

Comment: Hi @Fatmah instead using images try to copy the code, that way community can test it faster and you will get better solutions. It takes more time, but your effort will be rewarded in the same way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a math homework question.